# Storing an boost multi_index index iterator

Tags: c++, boost

I have a boost::multi_index class which has multiple indexes.

If i want to store a normal iterator i can do

multi_index_table::const_iterator x_itr == my_table.find(x);

but if i try

multi_index_table::const_iterator x_itr == my_table.get_index(y).find(x) it complains that it's not the same type of iterator.

I'm fairly new to C++ and come from a java background, ideally i'd like some form of superclass which is able to store any type of iterator if that's possibile.

Any guidance will be much appreciated!

EDIT:
I'm basically looking to do something as such:

```
my_table.get_index(a).find(x);
x.erase<a>(x):

my_table.get_index(b).find(y);
    x.erase<b>(y):   

template<uint64_t Index>
template<typename Iterator>  
Iterator erase(Iterator itr){
  my_table.get_index<Index>().erase(itr)
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `==` is comparison, not assignment? I cannot find `multi_index_table` anywhere in the boost documentation or via google for that matter. A superclass for all iterators does not exist. You would simply use `auto` in declarations to avoid writing inconvenient type names.

Comment: @user10605163 it's `boost::multi_index_container` (and a bunch of helpers in the namespace `boost::multi_index`)

Answer (score 2):

With c++11 is rather easy. Just use:

```
auto x_itr = my_table.get_index(y).find(x)
```

The compiler will figure out the type of `x_itr`.

Comment: The problem is I want to pass an iterator to a function

Comment: @MichaelFletcher This is a different question. To simplify your life, you could declare your function like ```template <typename IteratorType> f(IteratorType it)```. This has the advantage of generic code, and the compiler generates a different overload of ```f``` for every type of ```IteratorType``` that you pass to it.

Comment: Ah ha! that looks like what i need. Do you know how i can get the actual type of iterator?

I've attached an pseudo example to my main comment of what it is i'm trying to do.

Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: @MichaelFletcher each index has a distinct `iterator` type. There **isn't** a base class `iterator`, C++ shuns `virtual` as much as possible (rather more than Java). You *can* get names to each specific index's `iterator` e.g. `MyTableType::nth_index<0>::iterator` for the first, etc